# how to create a class in between php tags

Tags: php, html, function, class, pdo

I have 2 functions each containing a PDO object in a functions.php file that output html and are called in a different file. I am trying to organise my code and have put my database information outside of those functions and using them as globals.

I have read that using globals are bad practice so I though of having a class with the two functions inside, but as there is html inbetween the functions i'm finding it difficult to place them inside the class properly if it's even possible. best way I can demonstrate is with my code. How can I organise this in  a class?

```
<?php 

    $hostname = 'host';
    $db = 'database';
    $user = 'username';
    $pass = 'password';

?>

<?php function connectDB () {

    global $hostname, $db, $user, $pass;

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname; dbname=$db; charset=utf8", $user, $pass, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

    $sql = "query 1";

    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(//'placeholder',//'placeholder')); 
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

        while ($r = $query->fetch()): 

            $variable1 = $r['column1']; 
            $variable2 = $r['column2'];
            $variable3 = $r['column3'];
            $variable4 = $r['column4'];
            $variable5 = $r['column5'];
            $variable6 = $r['column6'];
            $variable7 = $r['column7'];

?>

//html code

<?php endwhile; } ?>




<?php function connectDB2 () {

    global $hostname, $db, $user, $pass;

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname; dbname=$db; charset=utf8", $user, $pass, array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

    $sql = "query 2";

    $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(//'placeholder',//'placeholder')); 
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

        while ($r = $query->fetch()): 

            $variable1 = $r['column1']; 
            $variable2 = $r['column2'];
            $variable3 = $r['column3'];
            $variable4 = $r['column4'];
            $variable5 = $r['column5'];
            $variable6 = $r['column6'];
            $variable7 = $r['column7'];

?>

//html code

<?php endwhile; } ?>
```

Comment: Take a read about: OOP, PHP Classes, static members in PHP, Factory classes, PHP Interfaces, Dependency Injection, MVC, Template engines (PHP can be used as a template engine as well, the requirement for a template is that it does no logic other than a couple of IF statements, some loops through existing data, and absolutely no data retrieval), Knockout JS or AngularJS for client-side templates and better UI, PHP namespaces and sp_autoload (learn to use it, with good file naming conventions and file structures)

Comment: This knowledge would help you: Design classes, use them correctly by avoiding globals, make your code testable via unit tests, make it readable.

Comment: `query 1` & `query  2` are not  SQL statements.